# I can't connect to database with data i got from an .txt

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to connect to a database using PDO and getting data from a .txt.

I got the data through this code, this gives me an array with the info from the .txt:

```
$servidor=file('servidor.txt');
$dbname=$servidor['0'];
$serv=$servidor['1'];
$user=$servidor['2'];
$pass=$servidor['3'];

if($pass = "''"){
    $pass="";
}
```

then, when I try to, it gives me a fatal error.

connection code :

```
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host='.$serv.';dbname='.$dbname.'',$user,$pass);
```

Does anyone know why this happens? if I swap the values from the array to the same values but as strings, it works perfectly.

Comment: What's the fatal error you getting?

Comment: "Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\burro\ligacao.php on line 14"

Comment: Where's the rest of the error?

Comment: it just appears like that

Comment: That seems unlikely. See if the error log has more information.

Comment: this is the entire php file

Comment: You know that your database credentials may be exposed if they get to /servidor.txt, I can recommend to have it as .php or even better create a config.php and have 4 constants varaibles with your db credentials.

Comment: May be useful to see the text file you are reading as well. You can change the password but dont change the format of the file

Comment: i know, im just testing

Comment: Which line is line 14?

Comment: the text file is on the post

Comment: Try changing it to `file('servidor.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

Comment: line 14 its the connection code that is on the post

Comment: Can someone reject the outstanding edit so we can add that code into the question please

Comment: it worked with FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES

Comment: If FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES has solved the problem, please mark the provided answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-returnvalues), `file()` will return an array but every line *will still include the newline* (`\n`) *character*. This means that you're currently connecting with username `"root\n"`, not (what you were expecting) `"root"`.

Either remove the newlines yourself or pass the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`:

```
$servidor=file('servidor.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```